# Copy static resources (js and css) from a war dependency to Grails application's web-app directory.

Tags: maven, grails

I have a project in Grails 2.1.3 and I'm trying to copy static resources like javascripts and css files from a war dependency to my Grails application's web-app/ directory. I'm trying to achieve something like war overlay. I tried generating the pom and using overlay feature of maven-war-plugin but it doesn't seem to work. Please, suggest a solution.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work"  What happens?  Is the war file in a maven repository?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the WAR file, then extract the contents with WinZip/WinRAR/7zip (or even with command line).

Then just copy over the files you need into your project's web-app directory.

This is, of course, assuming that you only need to copy these files over once, and not every time the app is run.